# Can use a NPS nut to attach a NPT nipple to a sink back

Tags: faucet, sink

I need to attach a wall  mount faucet to an old porcelain sink. I have a 3" nipple (NPT) and need a nut on the backside to draw the faucet down tight on the sink back splash.Will an NPS nut fit the NPT nipple correctly?

Comment: Maybe not correctly, but possibly _adequately_. Why ask us? Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

NPS is a straight thread and NPT is tapered.  For a pipe to fitting connection, you might get them to spin together but the connection would never seal properly as tapered threads rely on thread-to-thread contact for sealing and straight threads rely on compression of the fitting against an o-ring or gasket.

**Update**

Based on @isherwood's comment, I realize that I misread the question and you are asking about a backing nut, not a pipe-in-fitting situation.  In that case, sealing is not a concern, but I would still be careful since you didn't specify what materials the nipple and nut are.  If the nut is a material that is significantly harder than the nipple, it would be possible to damage the threads on the nipple and prevent it from sealing to the faucet.  If the nipple is harder than the backing nut, you'd probably be fine.

If I were trying to use a backing nut with a different thread taper to sandwich something to a fitting and my nipple was brass or another metal, I'd use something like this PVC backnut, expecting that the metal nipple would simply cut into the threads of the nut, leaving the nipple's threads undamaged.

This is, of course, in the case that you can't simply find a backnut with the right threading.

[image: PVC Backing Nut]

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. You are correct, I only need the nut to hold the faucet on the sink, not seal. I tried using a short nipple with a washer against the 90 to essentially squeeze the two against the sink back, but it leaked .I have brass or galvanized nipples available

Comment: I really like the PVC back nut! May use two on each side for durability